# HTML5 Canvas base64

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, base64

[image]

I am trying to save an image on a partcular canvas and reproduce it on another one. I am saving it as a string using a base64 encode. My problem is i seem to be loosing some info on the way from encoding to decoding. How can i stop this?? I have attached the image as well

```
      SignatureCapture.js

            function SignatureCapture( canvasID ) {
this.touchSupported = Modernizr.touch;
this.canvasID = canvasID;
this.canvas = $("#"+canvasID);
this.context = this.canvas.get(0).getContext("2d"); 
this.context.strokeStyle = "#000000";
this.context.lineWidth = 1;
this.lastMousePoint = {x:0, y:0};

this.canvas[0].width = this.canvas.parent().innerWidth();

if (this.touchSupported) {
    this.mouseDownEvent = "touchstart";
    this.mouseMoveEvent = "touchmove";
    this.mouseUpEvent = "touchend";
}
else {
    this.mouseDownEvent = "mousedown";
    this.mouseMoveEvent = "mousemove";
    this.mouseUpEvent = "mouseup";
}

this.canvas.bind( this.mouseDownEvent, this.onCanvasMouseDown() );
    }

    SignatureCapture.prototype.onCanvasMouseDown = function () {
var self = this;
return function(event) {
    self.mouseMoveHandler = self.onCanvasMouseMove()
    self.mouseUpHandler = self.onCanvasMouseUp()

    $(document).bind( self.mouseMoveEvent, self.mouseMoveHandler );
    $(document).bind( self.mouseUpEvent, self.mouseUpHandler );

    self.updateMousePosition( event );
    self.updateCanvas( event );
}
       }

    SignatureCapture.prototype.onCanvasMouseMove = function () {
var self = this;
return function(event) {

    self.updateCanvas( event );
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
}
    }

        SignatureCapture.prototype.onCanvasMouseUp = function (event) {
var self = this;
return function(event) {

    $(document).unbind( self.mouseMoveEvent, self.mouseMoveHandler );
    $(document).unbind( self.mouseUpEvent, self.mouseUpHandler );

    self.mouseMoveHandler = null;
    self.mouseUpHandler = null;
}
     }

      SignatureCapture.prototype.updateMousePosition = function (event) {
var target;
if (this.touchSupported) {
    target = event.originalEvent.touches[0]
}
else {
    target = event;
}

var offset = this.canvas.offset();
this.lastMousePoint.x = target.pageX - offset.left;
this.lastMousePoint.y = target.pageY - offset.top;

   }

   SignatureCapture.prototype.updateCanvas = function (event) {

this.context.beginPath();
this.context.moveTo( this.lastMousePoint.x, this.lastMousePoint.y );
this.updateMousePosition( event );
this.context.lineTo( this.lastMousePoint.x, this.lastMousePoint.y );
this.context.stroke();
    }

      SignatureCapture.prototype.toString22 = function () {

var dataString = this.canvas[0].toDataURL();
alert(dataString);
return dataString;




       }

     SignatureCapture.prototype.clear = function () {

var c = this.canvas[0];
this.context.clearRect( 0, 0, c.width, c.height );
      }

          main.js

    var sigCapture = null;

    $(document).ready(function(e) {

sigCapture = new SignatureCapture( "signature" );


$("#cancel").click( onCancelClick );
     });



    function onSC() {


    $("#feedback").html( "Tushar Babu23" );

    //var email = $("#email").val();
    var sig = sigCapture.toString22();
    console.log(sig)

    var img = new Image();
    img.src = sig;

    img.onload = function()
    {

    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    context.drawImage(img,0,0, 300,200);
    context.lineWidth = 5;
        }

        }

     function onCancelClick( event ) {
clearForm();
     }

    function clearForm() {
$("#email").val( "" );
sigCapture.clear();
$("#feedback").html( "" );
    }

   function requestSuccess( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
clearForm();
$("#feedback").html( "Thank you." );
   }

   function requestError( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
$("#feedback").html( "Error: " + errorThrown );
    }

   function verifyEmail() {
var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]                {1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
return re.test( $("#email").val() );
   }

            index.html


   <title>Signature Capture</title>

    <script src="js/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/modernizr.custom.34982.js"></script>

       <script src="js/application 222222.js"></script>
       <script src="js/signatureCapture.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/styles.css" />

     </head>

     <body>

<img src="assets/phonegap.png" />

<h2>SAMPLE FORM</h2>
<div></div>

<h2>EMAIL</h2>
<input id="email" type="email" />

<h2>SIGNATURE</h2>
<div id="canvasContainer" >
    <canvas id="signature" height="200px" />
</div>

<div  id="canvasContainer">
    <canvas  id="myCanvas" height="200px" />
</div>

<div id="lowerControls">
    <div id="feedback"></div>
    <div id="buttonsContainer">
        <input type="image" onclick="onSC()" src="assets/accept.png" />
        <input type="image" id="cancel" src="assets/cancel.png" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The SigCapture.toString is just a function that returns the "dataString"

Comment: My Source  - http://www.tricedesigns.com/2011/12/21/capturing-user-signatures-in-mobile-applications/

Comment: The code looks basically fine. You can see in these two basic fiddles for [shapes](http://jsfiddle.net/jbalsas/QhFuh/2/) and [lines](http://jsfiddle.net/jbalsas/QhFuh/3/) that it works just fine. I see in the SignatureCapture code that lineWeight is set to 1. Maybe that and the way the pixels are being tracked is provoking some kind of rounding error that accounts for the missing pixels.

Comment: Sorry, not quite interested in looking at code that is not properly indented. I guess the solution is more important to you than me. Put some effort into the question.

Answer (score 1):

Just use dataString, instead of this wierd sig stuff.

```
img.src = dataString;
img.onload = function(){
    context.drawImage(img,0,0, 300,200);
}
```

Are the two canvases the exact same size?

Comment: yes they are, and dataString is the returned by another function, shall try it

Comment: i did what you asked, the image came properly only, but the problem persisted.....

Comment: try using context.drawImage(img,0,0); and check the size of the image. I think it might be smaller than the canvas.

Comment: did that too, size goes way out of canvas' bounds, 300, 200 is correct only

Comment: try using .toDataURL() the regular, instead of this funny selector.

Comment: Like: var dataString = document.getElementById('yourCanvas').toDataURL();

Comment: again same, doesnt make any difference

Comment: isnt there anyway to draw the ommitted parts on our own

Comment: okay, that's alot of messy code right there. I can't debug it, since I am missing many scripts. Well I think the problem is that the image you get from your first canvas, is small. Way to small, and not real size. So it gets resesized when you draw it.

Comment: Fine i got the pic right but now i dont want to store the canvas image as a base64 string i just want to save it as an iomage file is that possible??

Comment: Yes, You can add an <img> tag and make src equal to the string.